# Nodemailer and Hostmonster: Receive 250 OK but unable to send email to external domains

Tags: node.js, smtp, cpanel, nodemailer, hostmonster

Here's my nodemailer config:

```
var mailTransporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "mail.domain.com",
  port: 26,
  auth: {
    user: account@domain.com,
    pass: RESET_PASSWORD
  },
  secureConnection: true,
  debug: true,
  logger: true
});
```

I receive a 250 OK response when I send an email, but it is not received by external domains, even spam checkers such as http://isnotspam.com/

However, it is received by users on the same domain (any-user@domain.com)

I have no problems sending to external domains when using the cPanel webmail or Thunderbird.
I've tried to configure `nodemailer` to be very similar to Thunderbird, but still no luck.

I've tried different ports supported by Hostmonster such as port 465, same result.

Comment: Hey, how did you solve this? I'm struggling with the same issue. 250 OK, but e-mail doesn't reach the destination.

Comment: I migrated away from Hostmonster, unfortunately. =\